# Сопоставление нескольких таблиц

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется 2 таблицы с разным количеством строк и столбцов. Таблицы объединяет одно поле: name

Нужно сделать так, чтобы одна таблица взяла индексы из другой по полю name

```
tab 1
id | name    | value1 | value2| value3| ....
0  | name1   | some1  | some2 | some3 | ....
1  | name2   | some1  | some2 | some3 | ....
...
500| name500 | some   | some  | some  | ....

tab 2

id | value| value | value | name    | ...
0  | some | some  | some  | name500 | ...
1  | some | some  | some  | name2   | ...
...
900|some  | some  | some  | name1   | ...
```

Мне нужно добавить индексы из второй таблицы в последний столбец первой

```
tab 1 upgrade

tab 1
id | name    | value1 | value2| value3| .... | id_from_tab2
0  | name1   | some1  | some2 | some3 | .... | 900
1  | name2   | some1  | some2 | some3 | .... | 1
...
500| name500 | some   | some  | some  | .... | 0
```

Обе таблицы импортятся из csv
 Пробую что-то вроде:

```
import pandas as pd

tab1 = pd.read_csv( PATH, sep=';')
tab2 = pd.read_csv( PATH, sep=';')

for i in tab1['name']:
    if i in tab2['name']:
        tab1['id_from_tab2'] = tab2['id']

   ...и т.д.
```

Подобным образом это не работает. Явно я не понимаю каких-то базовых вещей и нужно углубляться, тем не менее хотел бы понять как решается именно эта задача и буду рад помощи.

Comment: В Pandas есть join прямо как в SQL

Comment: На будущее - приводите воспроизводимые примеры своих исходных данных, если хотите получить ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем использовать циклы, если можно воспользоваться векторизацией? В противном случае теряется весь смысл pandas.

Исходные данные:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'name':['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'value1':['f','o','o']}
b = {'name':['name3', 'name5', 'name2'], 'value1':['b','a','r']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

То есть:

```
    name value1
0  name1      f
1  name2      o
2  name3      o
    name value1
0  name3      b
1  name5      a
2  name2      r
```

Можно сделать так:

1.

```
df1['new'] = df1['name'].apply(lambda x: df2[df2['name']==x].index[0])
df1
```

Результат:

```
    name    value1  new
0   name1   f       1
1   name2   o       2
2   name3   o       0
```

Но! если у вас будут несоответствия в значениях в колонке names, этот способ не сработает.

Поэтому вернее будет делать так:

```
df2['new'] = df2.index.astype('object')
res = df1.set_index('name').join(df2.set_index('name'), rsuffix='_r').reset_index()
res
```

Результат:

```
    name value1 value1_r new
0  name1      f        a   1
1  name2      o        r   2
2  name3      o        b   0
```

В данном случае, даже если у вас будет на соответствие в колонках обоих фреймов, отсутствeеющие значения будут переданы как Nan.

Возможно (надеюсь), коллеги оптимизируют мой join - у меня мало времени сейчас

**UPDATE** (as per MaxU):

как посоветовал MaxU, проще и эффективнее будет сделать так:

```
df2['new'] = df2.index.astype('object')
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='name')
```

В этом случае df1 будет:

```
    name value1_x value1_y idx
0  name1        f        a   1
1  name2        o        r   2
2  name3        o        b   0
```

Comment: Если связывать таблицы по столбцу, а не по индексу, то лучше использовать метод df.merge(df2, on=“column_name”)

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как-то смерджить только одно поле?? Пробовал по принципу df1 = df1.merge(df2['col-n'], left_on='some',right_on='some')  но это не срабатывает

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос - вы должны мержить некоторые поля в обоих фреймах по одному ключу. Если мы указываете только одну колонку, и она же является ключом, то мержить будет *нечего* (хотя код завершиться без ошибок). Если же указываете одну колонку, которая ключом не является, то, соответственно, у вас не будет этого ключа. и мержить будет *не по чему* (и вы получите ошибку).